# Mostrar el total sobre las barras en matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

tal vez esto sea algo obvio pero recién estoy empezando. Tengo esta base de datos:
[image: base de datos]

Y estoy intentando sumar todas las ventas(sale) agrupándolas por ciudad, hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
ventas_ciudad = df.groupby("city")["sale"].sum().plot(kind="bar")
```

[image: ventas por ciudad]

Pero no encuentro la forma de que este ordenado de mayor a menor, ni de ponerle la cantidad total encima de las barras para una mejor visualización. Espero sus consejos, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Antes que nada, cuando hagas preguntas en stack overflow es mejor hacer una sola pregunta por publicación para que otros usuarios al buscar información puedan encontrarla claramente

En este caso tienes 2 preguntas:

1. ¿Cómo ordenar un `groupby()`
2. ¿Cómo poner el valor de la columna encima de la barra?

También es necesario incluir todos los datos en forma de texto (Con formato de código cuando sea necesario) para que sea más fácil trabajar con el problema, en este caso te hizo falta agregar los datos de tu `dataframe`. Como puedes ver en la imagen final para Chicago ya me dio flojera copiar tus datos y puse cualquier cosa.

Respuestas:

1. Ordenar `groupby()`:

---

Para ordenar un `groupby()` hay que hacer un poco de "magia" con el `dataframe` para que entienda lo que queremos hacer

Es necesario agregar una nueva columna al grupo que deseamos obtener, ya que sin esa columna no vamos a poder ordenar, para agregar una nueva columna utilizamos el método `agg()` ([Documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)). En este caso estoy agregando la columna `total_sale`

Luego utilizando el método `sort_values()` podemos ordenar la nueva columna `total_sale` y puedes elegir si es ascendente o descendente (Por defecto es ascendente)

Para finalizar podemos utilizar el método `plot()` para crear la gráfica

Línea de código completa:

```
df.groupby('city').agg(total_sale = ('sale', 'sum')).sort_values(by='total_sale', ascending=False).plot(kind="bar")
```

2. Agregar los valores encima de las barras

---

Para lograr acceder a las propiedades de las columnas asignamos todo el `plot()` que hicimos en la pregunta anterior a una variable, en mi caso voy a llamarla `ax`

```
ax = df.groupby('city').agg(total_sale = ('sale', 'sum')).sort_values(by='total_sale', ascending=False).plot(kind="bar")
```

Es necesario modificar cada una de las columnas y decirle que escriba un texto con el método `anotate()` ([Documentación](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/annotations.html)). En este caso para obtener la posición de cada texto centrado y arriba de la columna utilizamos los métodos `get_height()` (Obtener alto) y `get_width()` (Obtener ancho)

```
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(np.round(p.get_height(),decimals=2), (p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center', xytext=(0, 10), textcoords='offset points')
```

El código completo para que grafique de forma descendente y con los valores arriba de las barras

```
ax = df.groupby('city').agg(total_sale = ('sale', 'sum')).sort_values(by='total_sale', ascending=False).plot(kind="bar")
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(np.round(p.get_height(),decimals=2), (p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center', xytext=(0, 10), textcoords='offset points')
```

Resultado
[image: Gráfica de muestra]